# How to forecast using the Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have created tensorflow program in order to for the close prices of the forex. I have successfully created the predcitions but failed understand the way to forecast the values for the future. See the following is my prediction function:

```
test_pred_list = []

def testAndforecast(xTest1,yTest1):
#     test_pred_list = 0
    truncated_backprop_length = 3
    with tf.Session() as sess:
    #     train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        counter = 0
#         saver.restore(sess, "models\\model2298.ckpt")
        try:
            with open ("Checkpointcounter.txt","r") as file:
                value = file.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("First Time Running Training!....")  
        if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists("models\\model"+value+".ckpt")):
            saver.restore(sess, "models\\model"+value+".ckpt")
            print("models\\model"+value+".ckpt Session Loaded for Testing")
        for test_idx in range(len(xTest1) - truncated_backprop_length):

            testBatchX = xTest1[test_idx:test_idx+truncated_backprop_length,:].reshape((1,truncated_backprop_length,num_features))        
            testBatchY = yTest1[test_idx:test_idx+truncated_backprop_length].reshape((1,truncated_backprop_length,1))


            #_current_state = np.zeros((batch_size,state_size))
            feed = {batchX_placeholder : testBatchX,
                batchY_placeholder : testBatchY}

            #Test_pred contains 'window_size' predictions, we want the last one
            _last_state,_last_label,test_pred = sess.run([last_state,last_label,prediction],feed_dict=feed)
            test_pred_list.append(test_pred[-1][-1]) #The last one
```

Here is the complete jupyter and datasets for test and train:
[My repository with code](https://github.com/JafferWilson/jupytertensorflow).

Kindly, help me how I can forecast the close values for the future. Please do not share something related to predictions as I have tried. Kindly, let me know something that will forecast without any support just on the basis of training what I have given.

I hope to hear soon.

Comment: May I know the reason for a downvote please? Where my question is lacking? I have provided every detail regarding the code, then why still a downvote?

Comment: Please someone can help me out what I can do here. I would love to hear suggestions, if any.

Comment: To make predictions on unknown data using a model, you need to save the model first(just like the way you use pickel to save python objects). Upon saving a tensorflow model, the values of weights and biases are saved to a file (having etension .pb). To know more on saving and restoring the model please refer to [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

Comment: @bbhatta13 Even if I save or restore the model, how is it possible to forecast the future values using it. Can you show something regarding it? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, by forecasting you mean predicting multiple closing prices in future (for example next 5 closing prices from current state). I went through your jupyter notebook. In short, you can not easily do that.

Right now your code takes the last three positions defined by multiple futures (open/low/high/close prices and some indicators values). Based on that you predict next closing price. If you would like to predict even further position, you would have to create an "artificial" position based on the predicted closing price. Here you can approximate that open price is same as previous closing, but you can only guess high and low prices. Then you would calculate other futures/values (from indicators) and use this position with previous two to predict next closing price. You can continue like this for future steps.

The issue is in the open/low/high prices because you can only approximate them. You could remove them from data, retrain the model, and make predictions without them, but they may be necessary for indicators calculations.

---

I somehow compressed your code here to show the approach of predicting all OHLC prices:

```
# Data
xTrain = datasetTrain[
    ["open", "high", "low", "close", "k",
     "d", "atr", "macdmain", "macdsgnal",
     "bbup", "bbmid", "bblow"]].as_matrix()
yTrain = datasetTrain[["open", "high", "low", "close"]].as_matrix()

# Settings
batch_size = 1
num_batches = 1000
truncated_backprop_length = 3
state_size = 12

num_features = 12
num_classes = 4

# Graph
batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
    dtype=tf.float32,
    shape=[None, truncated_backprop_length, num_features],
    name='data_ph')
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
    dtype=tf.float32,
    shape=[None, num_classes],
    name='target_ph')


cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=state_size)
states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    inputs=batchX_placeholder,
    dtype=tf.float32)

states_series = tf.transpose(states_series, [1,0,2])

last_state = tf.gather(
    params=states_series,
    indices=states_series.get_shape()[0]-1)

weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([state_size, num_classes]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]))

prediction = tf.matmul(last_state, weight) + bias


loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(last_label, prediction))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

# Training
for batch_idx in range(num_batches):
    start_idx = batch_idx
    end_idx = start_idx + truncated_backprop_length


    batchX = xTrain[start_idx:end_idx,:].reshape(batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_features)
    batchY = yTrain[end_idx].reshape(batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_classes)


    feed = {batchX_placeholder: batchX, batchY_placeholder: batchY}

    _loss, _train_step, _pred, _last_label,_prediction = sess.run(
        fetches=[loss, train_step, prediction, last_label, prediction],
        feed_dict=feed)
```

I think it is not important to write the whole code plus I don't know how are the indicators calculated. Also you should change way of data feeding because right now it only works with batches os size 1.

Comment: Ok got you point .. But is there anything else I could do, to make the forecast successful using my method, i.e. Using OHLC and indicator values to forecast the next prices? Can you help with that? Can you get me some workable model for it?

Comment: For example, you can create a model which predicts all OHLC prices (just a few changes in code) and then calculate indicators. Or you can predict more than one (for example 5) future closing price from the last step of RNN.
If you want to experiment even more, you can create Sequence-to-Sequence model. That would process know prices in first RNN and predict closing prices in second RNN.

Comment: Sounds cool. Can you just make the proper arrangements as per you suggestion in my code if possible. I would love to see it demonstrated. Theories are a bit not understood by me. Can you please add the working changed here in your answer?

Comment: I think it is not a point of this question to write a full code here, but you can contact me if you want to further discuss the problem.

Comment: Sure... How can I contact you? Can you join the chat room here?

Comment: Thank you for your help amigo

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your issue was resolved.  I was facing the similar problem and this is how I solved it -

- I used the same code, made some adjustments in number of neurons, batch size, past  history and the evaluation period.
- I ran the code with multivariate data to predict one step ahead.
- I fed the predicted value in the dataset
- Recalculated the indicators.
- And ran the loop for next 30 minutes (I was using 1 minute candle data)

This worked.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Can you share the code here? What you have made an attempt? Because above mentioned statements cannot be considered as answer but a suggestion. I cannot even upvote you unless there is code involved. BTW thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I used the code from here [link]https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=QIUxPv5PJOY&event=video_description&redir_token=DnakPmYgq_x0AaL3u3gkPmO7vxB8MTU3ODM5NTA2NEAxNTc4MzA4NjY0&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Franderson112358%2FPython%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FLSTM_Stock%2FLSTM2.ipynb

The problem that I found was that the predictions are showing values which are two steps in the past.  I have been reading about this and most of the people are saying that the model is doing naive forecasting as it could not learn anything.

Comment: I cannot even upvote your answer. Please let me know what is wrong and what you fixed. The code is must here. Secondly, people might downvote you if it remains without code. As the question is regarding the code.